# How to compute Ext and Tor of $(\mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z},\mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z})$ over the ring $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$?

Tags: homological-algebra, derived-functors

Let $m,n$ be positive integers with $m\mid n$. I want to compute
$$
\mathrm{Ext}_{\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}}^i (\mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z},\mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z}) \qquad \mathrm{Tor}^{\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}}_i (\mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z},\mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z})
$$
for $i \ge 0$. At first, I thought that the way to do this was to find a projective resolution of $\mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z}$ as a $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$-module, and I didn't know how to do that, so asked about it in an earlier question ([What is a projective resolution of $\mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z}$ as a $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$-module?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2259691/what-is-a-projective-resolution-of-mathbbz-m-mathbbz-as-a-mathbbz-n-m/2260434#2260434)).

However, the answer seems to depend on whether $m$ has repeated prime factors of $n$, so this doesn't seem like the way to compute these Ext and Tor groups. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Think of all of this as being analogous to number theory arguments involving multiplicative functions, where you work out how everything behaves for prime powers, and factor everything else into prime powers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll write $Z_n$ for $\Bbb Z/n\Bbb Z$ to reduce typing. Then a projective
resolution of $Z_m$ as a $Z_n$-module goes like this
$$\cdots\to Z_n\xrightarrow{\times n/m} Z_n\xrightarrow{\times m} Z_n\xrightarrow{\times n/m} Z_n\to Z_m\to0.$$
Dropping the final $Z_m$ and tensoring with $Z_m$, the Tor groups are
the homology groups of
$$\cdots\to Z_m\xrightarrow{\times n/m} Z_m\xrightarrow{\times m} Z_m\xrightarrow{\times n/m} Z_m\to0.$$
Then $\times m$ maps are 0, so the even Tor groups are
all equal the cokernel of the multiplication of $n/m$ on $Z_m$ and the
odd Tor groups equal the kernel of this map. I don't have the energy to
compute these further or look at the Ext groups...